# ZSH: Call in-built function from zsh function that uses the same name

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I use zsh and would like to slightly extend the in-built `cd` function.
I'd like that when I call `cd`, it changes directly and then lists the content of the directory.

```
function cd() {
    cd $1
    ls .
}
```

I'd have expected this code to work, but as it turns out, the call to `cd` refers to the function definition, resulting in an infinite loop.

Is there a work-around to solve this problem, apart from choosing a different name for my function?

**UPDATE**

Strangely enough, this worked

```
function cd() {
    `echo $1`
    ls .
}
```

No idea why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use builtin commands from within functions of the same name, or anywhere else for that matter, you can use the `builtin` precommand modifier:

```
function cd() {
    builtin cd $1
    ls .
}
```

`builtin COMMAND` tells *zsh* to use the builtin with the name `COMMAND` instead of a alias, function or external command of the same name. If such a builtin does not exist an error message will be printed.

---

For cases where you want to use an external command instead of an alias, builtin or function of the same name, you can use the `command` precommand modifier. For example:

```
command echo foobar
```

This will use the binary `echo` (most likely `/bin/echo`) instead of *zsh's* builtin `echo`.

---

Unlike with functions `builtin` and `command` are usually not necessary with aliases to prevent recursions. While it is possible to use an alias in an alias definition

```
% alias xx="echo x:"
% alias yy="xx y:"
% yy foobar
y: x: foobar
```

each alias name will only expanded once. On the second occurence the alias will not be expanded and a function, builtin or external command will be used.

```
% alias echo="echo echo:"
% echo foobar
echo: foobar
% alias xx="yy x:"
% alias yy="xx y:"
% xx foobar
zsh: command not found: xx
```

Of course, you can still use `builtin` or `command` in aliases, if you want to prevent the use of another alias, or if you want to use a builtin or external command specifically. For example:

```
alias echo="command echo"
```

With this the binary `echo` will be used instead of the builtin.

Comment: In bash, using `command cd` worked fine. When migrating to zsh I got a  `command not found: cd` error. Solved thanks to this post by replacing `command cd` with `builtin cd` for zsh.

Answer (score 2):

Why the `echo` command works is because you probably have the `autocd` option on. You can check this by typing `setopt` to get your list of options.

Then the echo-ing of the directory name and catching the output triggered the autocd and you went to that directory.