# macOS zsh script with parameters not working

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I am new to **zsh** and want to adopt my `bashrc` to work with the new shell. I had custom versions of the standard commands such as `cd` or `ls` and everything was working great in **bash**. In the **zsh** however the same code produces an infinite loop. May I ask how to port the code to work in the **zsh**, and why the error occurs?

Here is my code (located in `~/.zshrc`)

```
#clears the screen; then executes pwd and ls printing results in different colours 
custom_cd()
{
    clear
    cd $1
    tput setaf 135
    pwd
    tput setaf 220
    ls -a -F
    tput setaf 15
}
alias cd=custom_cd

# equivalent to (custom) "cd .", set to ls as well
custom_clear()
{
    clear   
    tput setaf 135 
    pwd
    tput setaf 220
    ls -a -F
    tput setaf 15
}
alias cls=custom_clear
```

Here is the command I enter:
[image]

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498409/zsh-call-in-built-function-from-zsh-function-that-uses-the-same-name

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Gairfowl, your link led me to fixing the issue. It turns out that when I was using `cd` with the *alias* active it was actually calling my method recursively, resulting in an infinite loop.

To fix this I used the `builtin` keyword in front of `cd` in the method, to specify that I am referring to the original builtin command. Now works perfectly, here is the fixed code:

```
#clears the screen; then executes pwd and ls printing results in different colours 
custom_cd()
{
    clear
    builtin cd $1
    tput setaf 135
    pwd
    tput setaf 220
    ls -a -F
    tput setaf 15
}
alias cd=custom_cd

# equivalent to (custom) "cd ."
custom_clear()
{
    clear   
    tput setaf 135 
    pwd
    tput setaf 220
    ls -a -F
    tput setaf 15
}
```